# What is maximum supported timeout for windows IOCTL command?

Tags: windows, timeout, ioctl, error-code

I am writing code to send SCSI direct command to device on windows. I am getting,

```
IOCTL ERROR : 87 (invalid parameter)
```

After debugging, I found invalid parameter was timeout = 608400 (7 days). 
Is there any document to tell max allowed timeout?